# Adding bootstraph glyphicon dynamically in asp.net mvc form with unobtrusive validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following javascript which successfully puts the red border and green border according to bootstrap

Please check the lines with - (the lines relevant for this question)

```
(function ($) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        validClass: 'has-success',
        validIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback',
        invalidIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback',
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass, validIcon, invalidIcon) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group")
            .addClass(errorClass)
            .removeClass(validClass);
            debugger;
            -$(element).next()
            -.addClass(invalidIcon)
            -.removeClass(validIcon);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass, validIcon, invalidIcon) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group")
            .removeClass(errorClass)
            .addClass(validClass);
            debugger;
            -$(element).next()
            --.removeClass(invalidIcon)
            --.addClass(validIcon);
        }
    };

    $.validator.setDefaults(defaultOptions);

    $.validator.unobtrusive.options = {
        errorClass: defaultOptions.errorClass,
        validClass: defaultOptions.validClass,
    };
})(jQuery);
```

}

The razor view its like this:

```
<div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaHasta, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaHasta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="help-block">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaHasta)
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Screenshot

Question: how can I dinamically add the glyphicons so that according to the boostrapframework when a field is valid it shows the green check and when its invalid it shows the red crosss.

http://screencast.com/t/Oat8DvZnsy

And it should show like this:
http://screencast.com/t/irp2fafnGx

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Can you post your JS, CSS to show glyphicon in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you HTML to

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaHasta, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaHasta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="help-block">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaHasta)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add CSS like so

```
.form-group.has-feedback > .form-control-feedback {
    display: none;
}
.form-group.has-success.has-feedback > .form-control-feedback.glyphicon-ok {
    display: block;
}
.form-group.has-warning.has-feedback > .form-control-feedback.glyphicon-warning-sign {
    display: block;
}
.form-group.has-error.has-feedback > .form-control-feedback.glyphicon-remove {
    display: block;
}
```

You might have to play around with the HTML a bit - I wasn't sure that .icon was for and I removed it. Also, wasn't sure what your styling for the .help-block was.

Anyway what happens is that adding the classes .has-warning, .has-error, or .has-success to the form-group (via your validation script) shows the appropriate icon.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to add some css classes to the span element using the next jquery function, however this is not working, maybe u misunderstood the question?

Comment: > which successfully puts the red border and green border according to bootstrap - I'd assume this already takes care of styling the form group. the above HTML and css will automatically take care of showing the correct icon when the form group is styled as success, warn or error.